# Grab a specific value from MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get a value from a MySQL database. I need to grab the **price** for the particular item and here is how my table looks:

[image]

I'm not sure how to go about this and the only thing I could think of to grab the price from the table was by adding a condition to the query where it only grabs results that match the `domain_address`.

I do the test by calling the function `<?php echo getPageURL();?>` which returns `http://vauxhallpartswarehouse.co.uk/` (which should match up against the database entry.

```
//table which calls function
<td bgcolor="#999999" align="center">Price: <?php echo getPrice();?></td>

<?php
function getPrice() {
    $con=mysqli_connect("host","user","pass","db");
    $price = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT price FROM domains WHERE domain_address='<?php echo getPageURL();?>'");
    mysqli_close($con);
    return $price; //should only be 1 result returned since domain_address is unique
    }
?>
```

This doesn't seem to want to work, and I don't really know how else to grab the price.

I know the connetion is fine and i already have this code further down the script which creates a table with all the results from the database, so maybe I could do something with the code below?

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("host","user","pass","db"));
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    $results = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT domain_name, domain_address, price FROM domains");

    echo "<table border='1'>
    <tr><th>Domain</th>....
    </tr>";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
    {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['domain_name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td><a target='_blank' href=" . $row['domain_address'] . ">"....
    //etc
    mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
```

Comment: You should consider to change your mysql credentials, as you have just posted them on the internet. I've made an edit for you

Comment: @donald123 they're fake

Comment: @donald123 `Failed to connect to MySQL: Connection timed out`

Comment: @donald123 the details are correct but password is different, this is a test-database anyway

Comment: Sidenote: You're already inside PHP, so why `'<?php echo getPageURL();?>'`? You should use `or die(mysqli_error($con))` to `mysqli_query()` that alone should have thrown you an error.

Comment: It's great that you're using the mysqli_ API, but now take a look at prepared statements.

Comment: @Strawberry whats the issue with using mysqli?

Comment: Who said there was an issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because in this line:

```
$price = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT price FROM domains WHERE domain_address='<?php echo getPageURL();?>'");
```

`getPageURL()` is not executed, it's just a static part of the whole string. Try this:

```
$price = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT price FROM domains WHERE domain_address='" .  getPageURL() . "'");
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to show any results. Anything else i can try? (It also removes my table below...)

Comment: Have you tried to just print the generated query itself (not its result)? You will see where the problem could be.

Comment: Turns out $price query returned an array, so I had to iterate through the array to get the result (although the array only holds 1 value)